# NodeJS can't take my DB values for my template

Tags: node.js, mongoose, templating, nunjucks

I started to develop a little web site in NodeJS, with admin authentication based on https://github.com/DanialK/Simple-Authentication, it work very well.

I can create a user, login with it and see the private page (dashboard).
But I have a problem with my template (I'm using Nunjucks), when the admin come to his dashboard I just wan't to show :

*logged as : 'admin_username'*.

This is my code :

**Model :**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  salt: String,
  hash: String
})
```

**Model definition :**

```
const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema)
```

**My route :**

```
router.route('/admin/dashboard', requiredAuthentication)
  .get((req, res) => {
    console.log("################ GET DASHBOARD ##################")
    requiredAuthentication(req, res, function() {
      User.find().then(user => {
        res.render('admin/dashboard.njk', {user: user})
        console.log(user)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
    })
  })
})
```

So I send "user", should be used in my **template :**

```
{% extends "base/layout.njk" %}

{% block content %}
 admin:dashboard page <br /><br /><br />

 {% if sessionFlash.message %}
   <div class="{{ sessionFlash.type }}">
     {{ sessionFlash.message }}
   </div>
 {% endif %}

 You are logged as : {{ user.username }}

{% endblock %}
```

With *user.username* I can't get the username.
With *user* only I get the entire document from the DB, username, email, salt, hash.

This is the result of the *console.log(user)* from the route :

```
[ { _id: 58c58ad8a5e54c00117ce85b,
username: 'test',
email: 'test',
salt: '/71BBVmr8E3b/HUz8L89IWLV7xM/vG9nvJRGzQYPw4dwR8GICr0kJtGs8dqwNzsMU7yki9aa2WM7C2NRxf/ausw+4kyiLojfugYzdrh+6obBq5HcZPZfQq+djwsTyyd+CDPJ/EmbUQyIL1yM7lRLfkhfrCIZ9P1mJZZM9fv4thw=',
hash: '��F\u0000\u000b ��a�\u001c|A˓P�N&��\u0010�5ajd�7{c �@�mQ����&��W�rW\'�+������\u0013����������N�4�y>/1��R\u001ca>���=U�u<9�T�o" \u000b�����Ʌ^�\u0004\u001f��\u0007�B`A�d���N@M$���',
__v: 0 } ]
```

Don't know if this is important, there is the two function used for authentication : *requiredAuthentication* and *authenticate* :

```
function authenticate(name, pass, fn) {
if (!module.parent) console.log('authenticating %s:%s', name, pass);

User.findOne({
    username: name
},

function (err, user) {
    if (user) {
        if (err) return fn(new Error('cannot find user'));
        hash(pass, user.salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) return fn(err);
            if (hash == user.hash) return fn(null, user);
            fn(new Error('invalid password'));
        });
    } else {
        return fn(new Error('cannot find user'));
    }
 });
}

function requiredAuthentication(req, res, next) {
  console.log("#### ->REQUIREDAUTHENTICATION() ####")
  if (req.session.user) {
    console.log("#### AUTH NEXT() ####")
    next();
  } else {
    console.log("#### AUTH DIE() ####")
    req.session.sessionFlash = {
      type: 'alert alert-success',
      message: 'You can't access the dashboard'
    }
    res.redirect('/admin/account/login');
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping me, if you wan't additional informations ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that `user` object is actually an array with 1 item. You can tell by that leading `[` in the console.log output. To fix the issue, you can either pass in `user[0]` to your render function, or add a for loop to your template in case you'll be grabbing multiple users later on.

Comment: Thank you it worked, in my template I used : {{ user[0].username }}, but it's strange because on another project {{ something.title }} work well !

Comment: Glad it worked! You can't always assume incoming data will be a single object or array, it will just depend on what API you're using. Although if I remember right, the Model.find() method in mongoose will always return an array, but don't quote me on that =)